# Applaunch creating new features and updating the status to edit new properties allowed

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-applaunch

In the new Bluemix AppLaunch service experimental, I created a new feature with few properties and metrics.

[image: ][1]]

Changed it from underdevelopment to Ready status..is there any way that I can edit that particular feature ?? or should it be another new feature?

Answer (score 1):

Once the feature is in Ready state, you cannot edit it. You will have to create a new one.